# No Method Errors in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was able to get a menu and pull up names of cat breeds, however when I continue to learn about the cat's breed I get this error down below. Not sure where to go from here. Am I suppose to delete something off? or perhaps try another api? really running out of ideas here.

Error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from bin/run.rb:5:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/jason/Development/code/Cat Breeds/Cat_breeds/lib/cli.rb:9:in `call'
        2: from /Users/jason/Development/code/Cat Breeds/Cat_breeds/lib/cli.rb:24:in `menu'
        1: from /Users/jason/Development/code/Cat Breeds/Cat_breeds/lib/cli.rb:44:in `list_of_breeds' /Users/jason/Development/code/Cat Breeds/Cat_breeds/lib/cli.rb:54:in `breed_selection': undefined method `get_metric_weight' for
#<CatBreed:0x00007fc581afc488> (NoMethodError)
```

in my cli.rb file

```
class CLI

    def initialize
        API.new.get_breed_data
    end
    
    def call
        greeting
        menu
    end

    def greeting
        puts "Welcome! Start searching for Cat breeds"
        puts ""
        puts "--To search for cat breeds, enter 'breeds'"
        puts ""
        puts "--If there is nothing you would like to do at the moment, enter 'exit'"
    end   

    def menu
        input = gets.strip.downcase
        
        if input == "breeds"
            list_of_breeds
        elsif input == "exit"
            goodbye
        else
            invalid_entry
        end
    end


    def goodbye
        puts "Goodbye!"
    end 
   

    def list_of_breeds
        puts "Select which breed you would like to know about:"
        CatBreed.all.each_with_index do |breed, index|
            puts "#{index + 1}. #{breed.name}"
        end
        input = gets.strip.downcase
        breed_selection(input)
    end


    def breed_selection(breed)
        input = gets.strip.downcase
        breed = CatBreed.find_by_name(breed) 
        if breed
            puts "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
            puts "Name of Breed: #{breed.name}"
            puts "Approximate Weight: #{breed.get_metric_weight}"
            puts "Approximate Height: #{breed.get_metric_height}"
            puts "Bred For: #{breed.bred_for}"
            puts "Breed Group: #{breed.breed_group}"
            puts "Average Life Span: #{breed.life_span}"
            puts "Temperament: #{breed.temperament}"
            puts "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
            puts ""
            puts "To continue searching for breeds, enter 'breeds'."
            puts "If there is nothing else you would like to do, enter 'exit'."
            puts ""
            puts "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
            menu
        else
            incorrect_breed_name
        end
    end


    def incorrect_breed_name
        puts "The breed name that you entered may have been spelled incorrectly."
        puts "Please enter 'breeds' to pull up the list and try again."
        menu
    end


    def invalid_entry
        puts ""
        puts "Hmmmmmm, I'm not understanding, please try again."
        puts ""
        menu
    end

    #binding.pry


end
```

something I'm doing wrong here? If you need more info let me know..

Comment: As the error message says, `CatBreed` (whatever it is) does not respond to `get_metric_weight`. Or, put simply, does not have a method or field/attribute with this name.

Comment: I can't quite tell but this may be a recursive menu system.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says:

```
/Users/jason/Development/code/Cat Breeds/Cat_breeds/lib/cli.rb:54:in `breed_selection':
  undefined method `get_metric_weight' for #<CatBreed:0x00007fc581afc488> (NoMethodError)
```

This error has got nothing to do with VSCode. It says that your `CatBreed` instance does not respond to a `get_metric_weight` method.

However, you have not shown the `CatBreed` class definition above, so I cannot comment further on the resolution.

Your code also assumes it has methods such as `get_metric_height`, `bred_for` and `breed_group`. If these methods aren't defined either, then I would expect a similar error to be raised once this issue is fixed.